# How do I track page cache miss in an amazon cloud instance?

Tags: linux, aws-ec2

Hi I have been using AWS instance to do perf experiment. Now I am interested to know the linux OS page cache miss rate for a given time window.

Online resources told me to try "cachestat" https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/fs/cachestat. However, if you read the link's comments, you can see that it have a strict assumption about the kernel version, because it checks some function name (which might be renamed in new kernel version). I tried it, it did not work for me. AWS page says we can customize our linux kernel https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html, but I am not strongly motivated to try that path, which looks like an error-prone and time-consuming journey at the first sight.

Have you successfully tried any other tool recently on AWS instance? thanks!